# Missing RedCloth gem but `rake gems:install` does nothing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, rakefile

I tried starting my Rails application but got this error message from Passenger:

```
Ruby on Rails application could not be started

The application has exited during startup (i.e. during the evaluation of 
config/environment.rb)

/home/chuck/chuck.com/vendor/rails/railties/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:119:

Warning: Gem::Dependency#version_requirements is deprecated and will be removed 
on or after August 2010. Use #requirement 

Missing these required gems: 
RedCloth 

You're running: ruby 1.8.7.72 at /usr/bin/ruby1.8 rubygems 1.3.6 at 
/home/chuck/.gem/ruby/1.8, /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8 

Run `rake gems:install` 
to install the missing gems.
```

I installed a Rakefile in my app and tried running `rake gems:install` but nothing happens and no error message is printed.

How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's rails-2.3.x, in your config/enfironment.rb

```
config.gem 'RedCloth', :lib => 'redcloth'
```

Answer (score 3):

I have found that gems:install is spotty because of the things that people put in their environments.rb files.  If this app isn't using bundler, you should `gem install RedCloth` and then try again.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a little more descriptive solution on how to fix this issue. You need to modify the environments.rd file and add

:lib=> 'redcloth'

Read my blog post here

http://spuder.wordpress.com/2011/08/04/missing-these-required-gems-redcloth/

Answer (score 0):

I'm also getting errors sometimes when I'm using Rails. I might wonder its something to do with super user command, like:

```
sudo gem install <gem name>
```

Because for me also `rake gems:install` does nothing and I have to manually install the gem as sudo (I'm talking about Linux box here).